# Retrieving the TabItem hosting a nested WPF Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some nested controls on a wpf TabControl.
I simply need to find the specific TabItem which is the parent of the control. Preferably using LINQ. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A non-selected TabItem don't exist in the Visual tree, but in the Logical tree.

I've made a small example on this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
     <TabItem Header="Test 1">
            <Button Content="Click to get TabItem Name" Margin="100" Click="btnGetParent_Click"/>
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem Header="Test 2"/>
</TabControl>
```

Clicking on the Button inside the TabItem should display the TabItem's header meaning you have access to it and you would be able to do any work you need.

I've kept the code pretty simple here too:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetParent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem ti = TryFindParent<TabItem>(sender as Button);
        MessageBox.Show(ti.Header.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is the helper method:

```
    public T TryFindParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
        else
            return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
```

The call to LogicalTreeHelper instead of the usual VisualTreeHelper does the job here.

Give it a try, i hope this helps.